# How do I dispatch to the "main thread" of Visual Studio correctly?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, add-in

Since [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc52cke4.aspx) doesn't say that Visual Studio Automation and Extensibility API is thread safe, I'm assuming it's not. So my question is, how do I return results from background threads to a thread that can safely alter Visual Studio's state?

Comment: I don't see anything about thread safety in the page you linked.  They don't have code examples in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually is thread-safe.  The extensibility object model is built on top of COM.  Which, unlike .NET, ensures that calls to objects that declare themselves to not be thread-safe are made in a thread-safe way automatically.  It does so by marshaling the call from the worker thread to the object owner thread.  This works without you having or being able to help.  Sometimes this causes disappointing performance and the dreaded "Waiting for background operation" message, but in general this works trouble-free without you having to do anything special.

Comment: IMHO this answers the question pretty soundly.